# How to determine which kind of plastic anchor to use on which kind of wall?

Tags: walls, drywall-anchor

I have a holder for a handheld shower head that I would need to install on a bathroom wall. This holder came with two screws and two different kinds of plastic anchors.

The anchors look as shown here:

[image]

What I wanted to ask is, how can I determine which anchor type to use on my bathroom wall?

Comment: What type is your wall? The left is for concrete/brick/masonry; right is for drywall. If it's drywall, screwing into a stud is far better than those poor anchors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger ones (on the right) are for drywall as the outer layer. The smaller ones are for inserting into a ceramic tile layer bonded to either drywall or cement board (or tile on cement board on drywall).